# Path Minimizing Distances on Semi-Algebraic Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, geodesic, semialgebraic-geometry

Let $M$ be a $k$-dimensional semi-algebraic manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Assume that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$.  We are interested in the Euclidean path minimizing distance between two points, $P: M\times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

1) In general, for a semi-algebraic manifold, the number of geodesics between a pair of points is infinite, e.g. two points on a cylinder have an infinite number of helical geodesics between them.  However, we make the assumption that our semi-algebraic manifold $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$.  Due to the non-compactness of $M$, is there a finite bound on the number of geodesics between two points $x,y\in M$?  If so, what is the relationship between the degree of the defining polynomials and the number of geodesics?

2) Computing the geodesics involves creating a system of ODEs using the Christoffel symbols.  I'm guessing that computing the exact closed form of the geodesics is impossible, even when $M$ is semi-algebraic.  However, is there a method of solving the resulting BVP to within some guaranteed error $\epsilon$?  If there are only a finite number of geodesics between a pair of points from question 1, is there a method to approximately compute all possible geodesics and thereby select the path minimizing one?

3) What can be said about shape of of $P$?  It must be $C^0$, but are there any convexity properties?  Let $f$ be some polynomial function of two points in $M$.  Can we globally minimize $f(x_1,x_2) + P(x_1,x_2)$ to within some guaranteed error $\epsilon$ over $x_1,x_2\in M$?